# Php joining strings not saving file

Tags: php

I have php function like this at start of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['visited'])) {
    $counter = file_get_contents('../visitCount.txt') + 1;
    file_put_contents('../visitCount.txt', $counter);

    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $dailyCounter = file_get_contents("../visitCount_" . $date . ".txt") + 1;
    file_put_contents("../visitCount_" . $date . ".txt", $dailyCounter);
}
$_SESSION['visited'] = TRUE;
```

As you can see what I want to do is have file with name `visitCount_XX/XX/XXXX.txt` but problem is that file is not appearing (saving) but first one (with static name does).

I have tried changing `''` to `""` just like it is in example now. I have typed `echo($date);` after everything and it shows me correct date. Why it Is not working?

Comment: It's not what you asked, but `file_get_contents` returns a string, and with that +1 at the end `$dailyCounter` will always be 1 as a result.

Comment: Did you try to change your date string to something else? (Just for testing) for example $date = "DATE";

Comment: Nope. it is not. As I said first file (visitCount) works normally, second doesnt

Comment: @TimSch It looks like it makes problem. Why doesn't it work and how to solve it

Comment: `/` is a __directory__ separator. You already have it in `../visitCount.txt`. Create another format for your date.

Comment: Changing `$date = date('d/m/Y');` to `$date = date('d-m-Y');` worked

Answer (score 0):

The slash is a directory seperator. So it's a reserved character. On Linux it may work to save a file that way when you escape it but it's not good practice.
On Windows it's completely forbidden.
Change your seperator to something like an underscore. That should work.

```
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$dateString = str_replace('/', '_', $date);
```

Otherwise you could do:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y');
```